# Elasticsearch with UI Dashboard Design in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am new for developing the ELK. So, I have an idea to do with the Elasticsearch data with some dashboard design using Kibana. I have tried we are able to create  dashboards like pie, graph etc. However, they are all based on the count and average related. So, I want data like table with whole data. But, a way of the form the query based on that it will generate table. I would like to know whether it is possible in Kibana?

Comment: Pick the data table visualization. You can also save a search in the discover view and then integrate that saved search in your dashboard.

Comment: @Val Yes I have done that also. but it show like count,average scenario only. I want some sepcfic column and based on some condtion.

Comment: Then the discover view is your friend, you can add filter, query, etc select the fields you want to display. When you're happy, you can save your search and then include it in your dashboard

Comment: @Val but it will not look like table, its showing like som unstructured view.

Comment: Do you mind sharing a screenshot?